# Errors in creating view-only wallet in Monero GUI v0.14

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

The first time I did it, it created the files with 'viewonly' appended to the file name and said to use the same password to open it.

So I closed the main wallet and browsed to the new view only '.keys' file that was created and when it prompted for a password, I used the main wallet's password but it said wrong password.

So I deleted those files and logged back into the main wallet and tried to create another view only wallet. This time, it creates the files but they look somewhat empty (smaller size) and there's also a '.new' file. Then Monero GUI blows up and disappears. Tried this several times, same thing.

The first time I did it, I did not export the view key. I thought that maybe this was the cause. The second and subsequent times I tried, I exported the view key.

**UPDATE
Went into Event Viewer and found this entry:

Faulting application name: monero-wallet-gui.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5c82818b
Faulting module name: Qt5Qml.dll, version: 5.7.0.0, time stamp: 0x5aeb3e6b
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000022b28d
Faulting process id: 0x27dc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d524840af68104

Maybe this might shed some light into the exception.

Comment: There's a bug in GUI v0.14.1.0 that results in the user not being able to properly use view-only wallets. This will be fixed in the upcoming GUI v0.14.1.0 release.

Comment: I'm going to download and try out v0.13 but can't find a link to the page that lists the older versions of the Monero GUI - would you happen to have the link?

Comment: GUI v0.13 is outdated and should thus not be run anymore. Please patiently wait until GUI v0.14.1.0 is released.

Comment: Ok, will do.----

Comment: So I downloaded v0.14.1.0 and the zip only has a subset of the files/folders that v0.14.0.0 has. Do I copy/paste these files/folders into a folder containing the v0.14.0.0? Is there a release notes file for this release?

Comment: "There's a bug in GUI v0.14.1.0 that results in the user not being able to properly use view-only wallets. This will be fixed in the upcoming GUI v0.14.1.0 release." - I see that you mention v0.14.1.0 twice. Is the upcoming release v0.14.2.0 or v0.15.0?

Comment: That was a typo. I meant that the bug present in GUI v0.14.0.0 will be fixed in GUI v0.14.1.0 (which is out now). It is advised to extract the file to a new directory. Instructions can be found here -> https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/c8eg6k/gui_v01410_boron_butterfly_with_ledger_nano_x_and/

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I did a search for 'v0.14.1.0' and saw comments from back in March mentioning this version so I was wondering if it was out then, when my question was from last month and also downloaded v0.14.0.0 around the same time. I would think that v0.14.1.0 would have come out after I posted this question. So anyway, the v0.14.1.0 zip only has a few files, much less than v0.14.0.0 - your reddit post doesn't mention combing the two versions.

Comment: When was v0.14.1.0 released?

Comment: There are literally only 17 files and no folders in this v0.14.1.0 zip and the file size is around 113 MB - is that right?

Comment: GUI v0.14.1.0 was released approximately two weeks ago. You must not combine the two versions. Rather, download GUI v0.14.1.0 (the zip file) and extract it to a new and separate directory.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The executable (monero-wallet-gui.exe) is now compiled statically to improve user experience (a single file is arguably more intuitive than a folder full of files :-P).